# How to distinguish an authenticated user at client side with Passport and node.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I use **`Passport.js`** with **`MongoStore`** for authentication, I use **`express`** as web framework.  Once a user has logged in he can access to content at a certain route.

**I'd like to offer distinct contents depending on which user has authenticated**. Let's say at Mongo collection of `members` each got a *`category`* or *`privileges`* attribute and upon of it I'll condition what to display to him.

I'll be using **`AngularJS`** for binding and rendering HTML.

> This is my routes managing:

```
app.get('/',function (request, response) {

    if(request.isAuthenticated()) 
        response.redirect('/admin')
    else
        response.sendfile("public/index.html")
})


app.get('/admin',function (request, response) {

    if(request.isAuthenticated()) 
        response.sendfile("views/admin.html") 
    else 
        response.redirect('/')
})

app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/admin',
    failureRedirect: '/'
  })
)

app.get('/logout', function (request, response){
  request.session.destroy(function (err) {
    response.redirect('/'); //Inside a callback… bulletproof!
  })
})

app.get('*',function (request, response) {

    response.redirect('/')
})
```

> And this is my **`Passport.js`** code:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/integraDB')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
var userCredential = new Schema({

    username:   String,
    password:   String

},  {
    collection:     'members'
})

var userCredentials = mongoose.model('members', userCredential)



app.use(session({
    clear_interval: 900,
    cookie: { maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
    store: new MongoStore({
      db : mongoose.connection.db
    })
  }));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
})

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
})

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    userCredentials.findOne({
      'username': username, 
    }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }

      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false);
      }

      if (user.password != password) {
        return done(null, false);
      }

      return done(null, user);
    });
  });
}))
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic wand you can wave to achieve this.  Passport stores the results of `deserializeUser` on `req.user` (you *are* using sessions, right)?

If we want to do something different based on user roles, we have two options.  One is to render a different view:

```
exports.home = function(req, res) {
  if (!req.user) {
    return res.render('anon');
  } else if (req.user.role === 'basic') {
    return res.render('basic');
  } else if (req.user.role === 'advanced') {
    return res.render('advanced');
  }
  return res.send(500);
};
```

The other is to pass `req.user.role` to whatever rendering engine you're using (I'll use ejs here):

```
exports.home = function(req, res) {
  var userRole = req.user ? req.user.role : 'anon';
  res.render('home', {
    role: userRole
  });
};
```

And then in `home.ejs`:

```
<% if (role === 'basic') { %>
  <!-- basic menu -->
<% } else if (role === 'advanced') { %>
  <!-- advanced menu -->
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks, very simple explanation. What if I'm not using any rendering engine right now (I know I should). How could I do it? I thought giving that work to Angular then. I also thought, for example for printing `"Hello SomeKittens"` to do a redirect to `/admin?user=SomeKittens`

Comment: @diegoaguilar No problem.  You can send the role variable back to Angular and manipulate as you please.  It may be best to keep it entirely server-side though.

Comment: I'm newbie about this. So let's say I keep it server side and then I want *credits* (for example) so when I do a get to `/credits` I can check, at server side `req.user.role` or `req.user.credits`. Or for example for displaing the typical "welcome User" I can make angular do a get to `/username`?

Comment: Head over to the [JS Chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript), we can help you out.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have to leave, unfortunately but for sure I'll be back later. Thanks again

Comment: You can also do some fanciness using Express's `Router()` to filter out users based on their permissions (since you can set custom middleware depending on what Route is loaded).  Just add a simple method call that will redirect them if their user permissions aren't valid.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica can you offer an example? :)

Comment: @diegoaguilar Yeah, I can later.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica I'll be really appreciated